# Ruby Variation with repeating buggy method

Tags: java, ruby

I need a method written in Ruby which computes Variations. I have already written it in Java, but as I'm new to Ruby, there's just something I'm missing about the Ruby implementation.

The method is supposed to do this:

```rb
method(1, "01") => ["0", "1"] <br>
method(2, "01") => ["00", "01", "10", "11"] ...so you get the idea.
```

note: in the Ruby implementation, I give params like this:

```rb
method(2, ["0", 1"])
```

but that's not an issue.

My Java implementation:

```
public static List<String> Variations(int strength, String usableChars) {
    List<String> list = 
        new ArrayList<String>((int) Math.pow(usableChars.length(), strength));

    if (strength == 0) {
        list.add("");
    } else {
        List<String> l = Variations(strength - 1, usableChars);
        for (char c : usableChars.toCharArray()) {
            for (String s : l) {
                list.add(c + s);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

And it's working fine. But this is my Ruby implementation:

```
def Variation (strength, arrayOfString)
    array = Array.new(arrayOfString.size**strength)

    if strength == 0
        array << ""
    else
        a = Variation(strength-1, arrayOfString)
        for i in arrayOfString do
            for j in a do
                array << (i + j)
            end
        end
    end
    return array 
end
```

In this, I keep getting an error message

```
test.rb:10:in `Variation': can't convert nil into String (TypeError).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby, arrays grow automatically as needed.  So change your array initialization from:

```
array = Array.new(arrayOfString.size**strength)
```

to

```
array = []
```

To enumerate over each character in a string, instead of

```
for i in arrayOfString do
```

do this:

```
arrayOfString.each_char do |i|
```

The final result:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

def Variation (strength, arrayOfString)
  array = []
  if strength == 0
    array << ""
  else
    a = Variation(strength - 1, arrayOfString)
    arrayOfString.each_char do |i|
      for j in a do
        array << (i + j)
      end
    end
  end
  return array
end

p Variation(2, '01')    # => ["00", "01", "10", "11"]
```

each_char is in Ruby >= 1.8.7, or you can get it from the [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports).

Comment: Thanks, works fine. I declared size of the array intentionaly, so as not to increase the size each time I add a new element (in Java i needn't declared the size either). Is there some way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: If I recall, Ruby reallocates array memory in chunks so that it doesn't have to be reallocated every time it is expanded.  But to allocate a array of `size` nils, `[nil] * size` will do it.

Comment: @user245543, I went back to the source (array.c); my memory is correct.  Ruby creates arrays with enough room for 16 elements and then grows it in chunks as needed (if I'm not mistaken, the more elements in the array, the more memory is added to it).  Time used to allocate arrays should seldom be a concern.

Comment: Is `each_char` ruby 1.8.7+ only?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, Yes, or from the backports gem.  Answer edited.